# float:right go to the next line

Tags: html, css

I saved my code to this site

http://jsfiddle.net/m6PnS/1/

help me!

Thanks

Comment: Do you need help getting your code out of that site again?

Comment: What is the problem? What result do you expect, and how does that differ from what you get?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that putting this little effort onto a question is really frowned upon here. Please in the future post a proper question, and the relevant markup. Nobody is going to look through the tag soup you're linking to.

Anyway, your problem will probably go away by placing the `float: right` element *before* the other one in your markup.

Comment: The button is on another tablerow also, the browser is actually doing what he told it to do

Comment: we're to good, closing question and still answering

Comment: Thank for comment ,sorry for my question.
My problem is that the second button on the right go to the next line :(
I want 2 buttons in the same line.

Comment: @bobby you'll have to place them in the same table row, and have the `float: right` one before the other one. That should work.